# How to solve complex transcendental equation?

Tags: equation-solving

```
    a = 22.86/1000;
    b = 10.16/1000;
    f = 10 10^9;
    c = 3 10^8;
    λ = c/f;
    d1 = 5 10^-3;
    d2 = 6 10^-3;
    λc = 2 a;
```

```
    λg = λ/Sqrt[1 - (λ/λc)^2];
```

```
    k1 = (2 π)/λg;

        Γ1 = -0.045420272 + 0.82392603*I;

        Γ2 = -0.064180885 + 0.81376999*I;
```

```
    Y[A_, B_] := (1 + (λg/(2 a))^2) (A - B*I) - (λg/(
    2 a))^2;
```

```
     NMinimize[{(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - Γ1, (
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - Γ2, 
      A > 0 && B > 0}, {A, B}]
```

Comment: `(0.0454203-0.823926 I)+(Sqrt[-0.7561+1.7561 (A-I B)]-I Tanh[0.790231 Sqrt[-0.7561+1.7561 (A-I B)]])/(Sqrt[-0.7561+1.7561 (A-I B)]+I Tanh[0.790231 Sqrt[-0.7561+1.7561 (A-I B)]])/.{A->1,B->1}` performs `0.622789 -1.95975 I`.

Comment: `NMinimize[{Abs[(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - 
         I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + 
         I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - \[CapitalGamma]1]^2 + 
   Abs[(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + 
         I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - \[CapitalGamma]2]^2, 
  A > 0 && B > 0}, {A, B}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` performs `{3.56646, {A -> 8.28942*10^15, B -> 9.00233*10^12}}`.

Comment: So where is the equation, I do not see any. Equation should have `==` in it.

Comment: Y[A_, B_] := (1 + (λg/(2 a))^2) (A - B*I) - (λg/(
    2 a))^2;
     NMinimize[{(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - Γ1, (
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - Γ2, 
      A > 0 && B > 0}, {A, B}]

Comment: A=7.2 and B=1.72, two equations, two unknowns.

Comment: How to plot above function with A and B range (0 to 10)

Comment: A=7.2 and B=1.72 are not equations, these are assignments. By these commands you assign values 7.2 and 1.72 to A and B, respectively.

Comment: NMinimize[{(Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + I*Tanh[k1 d1 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - Γ1, (
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] - I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]])/(
       Sqrt[Y[A, B]] + I*Tanh[k1 d2 Sqrt[Y[A, B]]]) - Γ2, 
      A > 0 && B > 0}, {A, B}]     Inside NMinimize two equations are there, we need to get  A and B values 7.2 and 1.72 respectively. But NMinimize solver giving some error. please help me how to solve how to get A and B valus?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to prove A and B values from the inside NMinimize equations.